# "Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" error

Tags: c

I am moving from Java to C and I am currently trying to design a linked list. In order to do this, I created a "node" structure which has a integer "val" attribute and a "dummy_element *next" attribute which is just a pointer to the next object. In the very beginning of the program, when it first starts running, no nodes should exist in memory, so I created a "Init_node()" function which creates a node called "first" and makes two external pointers "linked_head" and "linked_tail" point to the "first" node. Here is the relevant code:

```
    typedef struct dummy_element {
         int val;
         struct dummy_element *next;
    }node;

    node *linked_head;
    node *linked_tail;
    node *traversal

    void Init_node(){
        node first;
        first.val = NULL;
        first.next = NULL;
        linked_head = &first;
        linked_tail = &first;
    }
```

The whole point of the Init function is to initialize an empty node just so the pointers have something to point to. However, I keep getting the error "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" at first.val = NULL. Im not sure how to get around this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first.val` is of type `int` but you are assigning it `NULL` which is of pointer type. Change it to `0`.

```
first.val = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `first.val = 0` instead of `NULL`. You should keep `first.next = NULL` which is correct.

In time you will encounter code that zeroes the structure using `memset(&first, 0, sizeof first)`. While that also typically works, it has its problems (when all-bit-0 doesn't mean actual value of 0).

---

> ```
> /* Once the function ends linked_head will be invalid. */
> linked_head = &first;
> ```

This is besides the point but I have to warn you. You are storing the address of an object (`first`) that will die when the function ends. You may want to use `malloc` to create your `first`, like so:

```
node *first = malloc(sizeof *first);
if (!first) {
    /* malloc failed, the process is in trouble. */
}

first->val = 0;
first->next = NULL;
linked_head = first;
```